# How to apply blur to a UIView?

Tags: ios, image-processing, uiview, blur

Right now I am building an iPhone app that requires blurring an entire UIView. How can I achieve this? I have seen [this framework](https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit), but I don't think that works with UIView. Is there an alternate way to blur an UIView?

**UPDATE**: Check for my updated answer below, adding more relevance with the advent of iOS 7 and iOS 8.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ever since the release of iOS 7, This question has been getting a lot of hits and I thought I should follow up on what I ended up doing.

I personally blurred the picture at the time with photoshop, but there are many great third party libraries available that do ***dynamic*** and ***static*** blurring, here are a couple:

- This ingenious library takes a layer from `UITabBar` and applies to
  any view to get iOS 7's native blur:
  https://github.com/JagCesar/iOS-blur/
- This library is a real time blurring library that live blurs any view
  below it: https://github.com/alexdrone/ios-realtimeblur (as pointed out by qegal)
- Another one that does the same realtime blur:
  https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView
- This Library is the one I personally use and is ***Great***, allowing
  you to set the tint color among other settings:
  https://github.com/ivoleko/ILTranslucentView

I wanted to post this because you no longer **need** to take screenshots of individual frames or screen.

**iOS 8:** With the coming release of iOS 8, Apple has included a built in blurred `UIView`, `UIVisualEffectView` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uivisualeffectview)

Comment: FXBlurView works on iOS5+ [https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView).

Comment: Please note that at least one app got rejected from using some of these libraries (iOS-blur https://github.com/JagCesar/iOS-blur/issues/25). These libraries use a layer within `UITabBar` to achieve the effect, and Apple appears to be rejecting those.

Comment: This seems to have been fixed with a new commit. Plus the app that got rejected got rejected for another (main)reason.

Answer (score 47):

This should work. I commented in the code to help you understand what's going on:

```
//To take advantage of CIFilters, you have to import the Core Image framework
#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>

//Get a UIImage from the UIView
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.bounds.size);
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//Blur the UIImage with a CIFilter
CIImage *imageToBlur = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:viewImage.CGImage];    
CIFilter *gaussianBlurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CIGaussianBlur"]; 
[gaussianBlurFilter setValue:imageToBlur forKey: @"inputImage"]; 
[gaussianBlurFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 10] forKey: @"inputRadius"];
CIImage *resultImage = [gaussianBlurFilter valueForKey: @"outputImage"]; 
UIImage *endImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:resultImage];

//Place the UIImage in a UIImageView
UIImageView *newView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
newView.image = endImage;
[self.view addSubview:newView];
```

If you have any questions about the code, just leave it in the comments.

**Note:** CIGaussianBlur isn't present on iOS as of 5.1, so you must find a different way to blur the view for devices 5.x+ (Thanks to @BradLarson for this tip). The accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182788/how-to-get-the-gaussian-blur-effect-on-a-uiview-in-ios6) looks promising as a replacement, as does [this library](https://github.com/alexdrone/ios-realtimeblur).

Comment: Note that CIGaussianBlur isn't present on iOS as of 5.1, so you may need to find a different way of accomplishing this on 5.x and older.

Comment: You get the blur between self.view and myView in this code, right?

Comment: Hi @qegal , how can i change the intensity of the blurr effect ?

Comment: Is it possible to create a category over UIView with methods -(void)blur and -(void)unblur ?

Comment: but this behaives like it cuts an area around the view

Comment: so I checked the CIImage and UIImage objects in this code using breakpoints and found that the blurred image appears as it should in the CIImage object but the UIImage object isn't showing anything.. It says 'Cannot load quick load data for endImage' when the eye button is pressed on that object

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 13):

In iOS 8 you can use `UIVisualEffectView` to get blurred Views.
See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uivisualeffectview

Comment: If you set a UIVisualEffectView and then change the effect, how do you reload that view?

Comment: I don't think its possible to reload it when you change the effect - you have to init it again.

Answer (score 1):

Simply solved using this code.

```
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:yourView.bounds];
toolBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] >= 7.0) {
    toolBar.barTintColor = nil;
    toolBar.translucent = YES;
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
}
else
    [toolBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:5 green:31 blue:75 alpha:1]];
[yourView insertSubview:toolBar atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to blur a view is to add UIToolbar,just change the alpha value to change the blur.

```
self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initForAutoLayout];
[self.view addSubview:self.toolbar];
[self.toolbar autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeLeft withInset:0];
[self.toolbar autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeRight withInset:0];
[self.toolbar autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeTop withInset:NAVBAR_HEIGHT];
[self.toolbar autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeBottom withInset:0];
self.toolbar.alpha = 0.5;
```

Comment: This is discussed within the accepted answer. However, this is no longer efficient(or advised) with the launch of iOS 8 and the UIVisualEffect Classes and API's

Comment: So can we UIToolbar as a blur view for ios7,without using any 3rd party libs.