# How can I blur area?

Tags: objective-c, ios, draw, blur, uitableview

I have a UITableView and UIView (orange). I need that when I scroll a table, under orange area my table has a blurred. Can everybody help me? Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like described here: [Apply blur to UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130923/apply-blur-to-uiview)

But blurring is computationally intensive, and scrolling performance will most likely be bad.

Answer (score 0):

Make the orange view over the tableview, then set it's opacity.

Comment: I don't need to change opacity orange area. I need to blur area under orange view.