# Exception creating a UIImage from an AssetURL in monotouch code

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am getting an exception on my second line of code here.  I am calling this code from within ViewDidLoad.  _assetURLs[page] (in this case page is 0), is returning a single assetURL that exists and was already retrieved.

```
UIImage img;
img = new UIImage(new MonoTouch.CoreImage.CIImage(_assetURLs[page]));
```

Any ideas?

Here is the exception:
(the exception is happening because of --> new UIImage(...) and not because of new MonoTouch.CoreImage.CIImage(_assetURLs[page])

{MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[UIImage initWithCIImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107a1fc0   at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr (intptr,intptr,intptr)   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage..ctor (MonoTouch.CoreImage.CIImage ciImage) [0x00027] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIImage.g.cs:376    at ScrollViewPageViewExample.Viewer.LoadPageContent (Int32 page) [0x0002e] in /Users/user1/Dropbox/Dev/ScrollViewPageViewExample/ScrollViewPageViewExample/Viewer.cs:148 }

Comment: I'm not a monotouch user, but what exactly does "new" mean because it looks to me like you're trying to initialize the same UIImage twice. Try UIImage img = new UIImage(new MonoTouch.CoreImage.CIImage(_assetURLs[page]));

Comment: new, creates a new instance of the object. If I remember correctly this is similar to initialize an object in obj-c.  The syntax here is correct.  I am first initializing a CIImage with an Asset URL as part of the initialization to get that asset image url.  Then I am initializing a new UIImage with the CIImage being initialized with it (passed in as an argument to the constructor in C#)

Comment: Where is that code executed ? device or simulator ? and using which version of iOS ? i.e. that selector is new in 5.0 (4.3 would throw that ObjC exception).

Answer (score 3):

That an ([already fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13755014/220643), but not yet released) bug in MonoTouch.

You can use the overloaded constructor that accept a float and an `UIImageOrientation` as a workaround.

```
UIImage img = new UIImage (your_ciimage, 1.0f, UIImageOrientation.Up);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try it.  It's very difficult to hunt down this type of MonoTouch info on the web.  Several hours of google searching and following links on the subject didn't get us any closer to resolving this.

Comment: Somehow, we missed the stack overflow article you suggested.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I've created a new question on SO about this issue I am having with your recommended code.  It seems (to me, so far) the constructor for UIImage is not doing what it's supposed to.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464154/a-valid-image-not-being-returned-from-coreimage-in-monotouch-for-a-valid-asset