# A valid image not being returned from CoreImage in MonoTouch for a valid Asset

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiimage, uikit, core-image

I am trying to get an image using this.

```
img = new UIImage(new MonoTouch.CoreImage.CIImage(validAssetObject),1.0f, UIImageOrientation.Up);
```

A `CIImage` is returned from the `CIImage` call.  The new `UIImage` has the `CIImage` property = `null`.

Seems like the constructor for `UIImage` is not working as expected?

Any ideas from the MonoTouch community?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick test and this seems to work fine.

```
string file = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.ResourcePath, "image.png");
using (var url = NSUrl.FromFilename (file))
using (var ci = CIImage.FromUrl (url))
using (var ui = new UIImage (ci, 1.0f, UIImageOrientation.Up)) {
    Assert.IsNotNull (ui.CIImage, "CIImage");
}
```

Something else must differ but you have not shared enough source code to compare. Could you create a small test case, with your image, and file a [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) ?

Comment: What you need to do is test loading from an actual Asset URL from the media folder.  For example, save any photo in Safari.  Now get the asset url and load this photo from Saved Photos folder into an Image object.

Comment: There is enough code to compare.  Your mechanism for doing it is different.  Get any image asset url from Saved Photos media folder and try :)

Comment: It's not different, it's based on an `NSUrl` creating from a `string` - which is what you'll get as your input.