# How to get the gaussian blur effect on a UIView in iOS6

Tags: xcode, twitter, uiview, blur, gaussian

Does anyone know how to achieve a gaussian blur effect on an UIView in iOS6? Similar to twitter's #music app when the filter menu is open. (the background under the menu becomes blurred)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a library [RWBlurPopover](https://github.com/eternityz/RWBlurPopover) based on [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/) that can achieve similar gaussian blur effect when presenting a popover. Supports both iPhone and iPad, and runs on iOS 5.1+.