# Graduated Blur Effect

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, core-graphics

I'm trying to replicate this effect:

http://www.pinterest.com/pin/483503709967044672/

Where the image is not blurred at all at the top, but becomes more gradually blurred as you go further down. Ideally this would be a live effect in the same way that the iOS toolbar works.

I know I can adjust the alpha of a view, but I'm looking for something that can adjust it as it goes down the view, rather than just being static over the view.

Answer (score 0):

Well, its looks as if the app in the screenshot is using multiple `UIView`'s arranged in a vertical order and blurring them at different levels.This is ***really*** performance heavy. If you need help on how to blur `UIView`'s(especially in iOS 7), see my SO Question and the answers provided([How to apply blur to a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130923/how-to-apply-blur-to-a-uiview)).