# iOS map style config slide up?

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit

iOS 7 has changed how maps are displayed by apps on the iPhone, and especially how the user configures the map.

The map is displayed like this, with an Info button.

[image: Maps]

When the user taps the Info button, the configuration screen slides up.

[image: Configuration]

How do I recreate a screen overlay like this in my code? While I don't want the user to be dropping pins, I want the user to be able to switch between different map styles or open the address I'm pointing to in Apple's Maps app.

Comment: It seems as if apple just loads a custom view with options on how to set the different map settings using the segmented control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do a simple overlay view, then look into making an `UIView` slide up through `UIView` animations. Other than that, you would need an `UISegmentedControl` and related code. You would also need to blur the view and make it translucent, so look into my other question and answer on how to properly blur an `UIView`:[How to apply blur to a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130923/how-to-apply-blur-to-a-uiview)

Comment: I assumed that was a view controller, but now that I think about it this makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've never looked into it, but I've heard the only easy way to do a translucent background (as in, without writing your own OpenGL code) is to create a `UIToolbar` instance.

I'm guessing you'd make a toolbar with no items, just treat it like `UIView` and add your own subviews (`UITableView`, etc). It is a subclass of `UIView`.