# UIView background too blurry

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am trying to make a UIView (`Genres`) have a blurry background. I have tried this code. But it is too blurry:

```
_Genres.opaque = NO;
_Genres.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIToolbar *fakeToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:_Genres.bounds];
fakeToolbar.autoresizingMask = _Genres.autoresizingMask;
[_Genres insertSubview:fakeToolbar atIndex:0];
```

So I tried this:

```
_Genres.alpha = 0.9;
```

But this just makes it see through not less blurry.

The UIView also needs a "live blur".

These are two images. The first one is the actual toolbar (which I want it to be like) and the second one is using the code above. They have both been taken over the same background.

[image]

[image]

As you can see underneath the toolbar the blur is a lot less intense.

How can I make it more like the original toolbar?

Comment: You can use CoreImage as solving your problem Go for this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17041983/3797226)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want FXBlurView: https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView. If you need blur to be live set dynamic = YES.

Otherwise it just behaves as a UIView but blurs the stuff behind it

Comment: How do you set need blur to be live set dynamic = YES. I asked the same sort of question [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView/issues/69) but I got no answer

Comment: self.myBlurryView.dynamic = YES;

Comment: would you be able to help me with this problem too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542076/getting-uiview-in-separate-class-for-fxblurview

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS 7 and above, I believe that this article might be of help to you:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/60968/ios-7-blur-effects-gpuimage

The author uses new iOS 7 API to create blurs that will look in place in iOS 7. And the great part is that by changing one line of code, you will be able to experiment with other different types of blur.

Answer (score 0):

Don't even try to use `UIToolbar` for blur on iOS 7 unless you have some super special need for the so-called 'live blur'. Other than that I recommend you Apple's own `UIImage` extension. Check it out here:

https://gist.github.com/ShadeApps/a9c9944b80048ae200c1

Import it in your .m file:

```
#import "UIImage+ImageEffects.h"
```

Then use on `UIImage` it like this:

```
[ourImage applyBlurWithRadius:10 tintColor:[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] saturationDeltaFactor:0.0 maskImage:nil];
```

With this you can achieve better and faster effects with a ton of customization for your needs.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use this?

Comment: @rvijay007 anything else I might assist to your needs, sir?

Comment: Unfortunately I do have some `super special need for the so-called 'live blur'` as it slides in this uiview

Comment: @Maximilian then the only way to do it is using UIToolbar and that's it, I guess.

Comment: :( this sucks! I don't understand why it is more intense!

Comment: @Maximilian from their own `iOS 8` keynote they actually **DO** use different blur techniques here and there, so that's how it's intended to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

[Creating a blurring overlay view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041669/creating-a-blurring-overlay-view)

[How to apply blur to a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130923/how-to-apply-blur-to-a-uiview)

Also in iOS 8 it will be much easier, you can simply use `UIVisualEffectView`

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/