# getting UIView in separate class for FXBlurView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, superview

I am using [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView) but I am receiving a weird black line at the top when animating the blurView down.

I have a `UITable` that is 3/4 up the ViewController and an image that is the rest. What is happening Is that it is only picking up the `UITable` and not the image, in the superview. So is there a way to get the `superview` to pick up both? or a replacement?

[image]

I have read that this can be fixed by replacing the superview with the actual UIView

> FXBlurView captures the contents of its immediate superview by
>   default. If the superview is transparent or partially transparent,
>   content shown behind it will not be captured. You can override the
>   `underlyingView` property to capture the contents of a different view
>   if you need to.

The `FXBlurView.m` code is:

```
- (UIView *)underlyingView
{
    return _underlyingView ?: self.superview;
}
```

---

I have tried this:

```
((FXBlurView *)self.Genres).underlyingView = _main_view;
```

but this makes no difference

where `ImagesTableViewController` is my main `ViewController` containing the Blured Uiview and the one I want to replicate (`main_view`)

But this just creates a white page for the Blured Uiview.

Comment: In your last bit of code, all you're doing is instantiating a new `ImagesTableViewController` instead of getting your actual view controller instance.

Comment: How do I go about getting my actual view controller instance??

Comment: @DrBeardface can you help sorry?

Comment: Somewhere in your view controller code (maybe `viewDidLoad`), set the blur view's `underlyingView` to your view controller's `main_view`. You should not have to edit FXBlurView at all.

Comment: @DrBeardface How though?! That is my question?

Comment: @Maximilian its black because you set the color to clear view, if This view was pushed by another non clear it would not be black

Comment: @meda that is what I am trying to do in the question?

Answer (score 1):

First off you shouldn't need to edit the FXBlurView source at all.

Secondly I guess the black bar is part of the view hierarchy that isn't getting picked up. Maybe a navbar? You might try adding the blur view to the window rather than the view so you grab everything:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview: blurView];
```

Failing that the only hack I can think would be to make an imageView that grabs its image using the window like:

```
- (UIImage *)screenGrab:(id) theView {

   CGRect rect = [self.view bounds];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [theView.layer renderInContext:context];   
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

with:

```
[self screenGrab: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
```

Then set imageView.image to the grabbed image and set this as the underlying view. You shouldn't need to do this though :)

Failing that I'd need to see a bit more code to understand the view hierarchy.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance... Where do I place `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview: blurView];`

Comment: In place of where you add the blurview already. You are just adding it to the window rather than the normal view hierarchy. This is where e.g. a UIAlertView gets inserted into the app so you have to be a little careful but it *should* give you the entire app interface.

Comment: Hello Martin. I have tried the first method with no luck

Comment: Could I send you the project via email so that you can have a better look?