# iOS: Distance of 0.5 px between 2 views

Tags: ios, uiview

I want to clone this control but i don't know how to make a 0.5 pixels distance between two views. Any advices?

Another problem is I can't figure out how to do that blur effect on everything that is below current view. I tried to use alpha but it doesn't look the same.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130923/how-to-apply-blur-to-a-uiview

Comment: 0.5 _points_ (not pixels), 0.5 _points_ is 1 pixel on a retina screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I want to clone this control but i don't know how to make a 0.5 pixels distance between two views. Any advices?*

In Storyboard when you hold an widget (For e.g.: UITextField) and press alt at the same time, it will show you its alignments with the other widgets. From there you can see whether its having specific pixel distance or not.

*Another problem is I can't figure out how to do that blur effect on everything that is below current view. I tried to use alpha but it doesn't look the same.*

- Create a popup view (inherited by `UIView`)
- Set background color as `[UIColor clearColor]`
- Add an imageView in background to fill entire view
- Set `whiteColor` as a background color for this imageView
- Set alpha property as per your requirement (for e.g.: `imageView.alpha = 0.5f`; )

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for answering me but your solution is not what i'm looking for.